# Special copy&paste-script for .csv files

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have a partial solution for a former question I asked, I hope it's okay to open a new question.

What I have:

.csv-file 1

```
00|G1|G2| 
K4|__|X_|
K5|X_|X_|
```

.csv-file 2

```
00|G3|G7|G9|G12  
K6|X_|__|X_|__|  
K7|__|X_|X_|__|  
K8|__|__|__|X_|
```

What I want:

final .csv (or .xls) file

```
00|G1|G2|G3|G7|G9|G12  
K4|__|X_|__|__|__|__|  
K5|X_|X_|__|__|__|__|  
K6|__|__|X_|__|X_|__|  
K7|__|__|__|X_|X_|__|  
K8|__|__|__|__|__|X_|
```

So the top row of file 2 -- shall be added to the right -- of the top row of file 1.

The first column to the left of file 2 -- shall be added underneath -- the first column of file 1.

The corresponding Xes shall then be just copy and pasted -- to the down right corner -- of the Xes of file 1.

I have a lot of .csv-files and no idea how to use VBA.

I'd very much appreciate your help!

Regards,
Tom

Comment: No, not really. As I said, unfortunately I've got no clue how to use VBA and I'm on a machine without any other programming-environment.

Pseudocode should look something like this:


`x_C=1;`  
`x_R=1;`

`for (i=1;i<=number_of_colums;i++) {`

`column_array[i]=content_of_column_i; // in row 1`
`x_C++;`
`}`

`for (j=1;j<=number_of_rows;j++) {`
`row_array[j]=content_of_row_j; // in column A`
`x_R++;`
`}`

`copy(A2:(x_C|x_R)) to (number_of_columns_file_1 + 1 : number_of_rows_file_1 + 1);`

Comment: Why do you want to loop through the data? It looks like you just want to append the data from one file 2 to file 1.

Comment: Hm, alright. Dunno what's possible in VBA:

Maybe more like this then:

`copy row_1 of file_2` to `number_of_colums_file_1 + 1`

`copy column_1 of file_2`to `number_of_rows_file_1 + 1`

`copy content_of_array[B2:EoF]` to `old number_of_colums_and_rows_of_file_1 + 1 | new_number_of_columns_and_rows_file_1 + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it's a bit convoluted but I think this is what you want. I've put it so they are in the same workbook but that is easily changed to opening the files with setting a workbook with Workbooks.Open()

Edit to show how I do to an open csv. (there are many ways you can do all the below)

---

```
Sub simplePaste()

Dim lastRow0 As Long
Dim lastColumn0 As Long
Dim lastColumn1

Dim ws0 As Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Dim wb1 As Workbook


Dim CopyRange As Range
Dim pasteRange As Range

Set ws0 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\james\Desktop\source.csv")
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets(1)

lastRow0 = ws1.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
lastColumn0 = ws1.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column
lastColumn1 = ws0.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column

Set CopyRange = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, 1), ws1.Cells(lastRow0, lastColumn0))
Set pasteRange = ws0.Cells(1, lastColumn1 + 1)

CopyRange.Copy
pasteRange.PasteSpecial

wb1.Close


End Sub
```

Comment: Hey @jamesC,

thanks for your efforts but unfortunately that's not what i wanted. (;

This script just copies Sheet2 next to the data of Sheet1.

I'm trying to understand your code and get back to you in a minute! (:

Thanks so far

Comment: yes. the important bit is the copying of the ranges. It's easy to reference your csv's once you open them so the same principles apply you would just change sheet2 to be your source csv and sheet1 to be the target where you will paste the data.

Comment: @tom I've updated to show you how you can open the csv

Comment: Ah nice, that was the last piece I was missing. 

I just finisched editing your code I'll post it in the answer.

Thank you very much!

Comment: @tom great glad to help but on SO the person who asks the question doesn't post the answer. You accept the answer that solved your issue. Unless you solved your issue another way

Comment: Uh, sorry, I'm kinda new here (obviously). 

I just wanted to post the _full_ solution (which I just did).

Hope thats alright!
And thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

So this code should do the trick, it only misses some kind of function to crawl through your directory and open the files one by one. But that doesnt seem to hard to write.

Sub simplePaste()

```
Dim lastRow0 As Long
Dim lastColumn0 As Long
Dim lastColumn1

Dim ws0 As Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Dim CopyRange As Range
Dim pasteRange As Range

Set ws0 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

lastRow0 = ws0.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
lastColumn0 = ws0.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column


lastRow1 = ws1.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
vlastColumn1 = ws1.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column


Set CopyRange = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, 2), ws1.Cells(1, lastColumn1))
Set pasteRange = ws0.Cells(1, lastColumn0 + 1)

CopyRange.Copy
pasteRange.PasteSpecial


Set CopyRange = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(2, 1), ws1.Cells(lastRow1, 1))
Set pasteRange = ws0.Cells(lastRow0 + 1, 1)

CopyRange.Copy
pasteRange.PasteSpecial

Set CopyRange = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(2, 2), ws1.Cells(lastRow1 - 1, lastColumn1))
Set pasteRange = ws0.Cells(lastRow0 + 1, lastColumn0 + 1)

CopyRange.Copy
pasteRange.PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

What it does:

1. get the count of rows and columns in each sheet
2. set the copy range for the first row in sheet 2
3. set the paste cell in sheet 1 (first cell with no content in row 1)
4. paste
5. set the copy range to the first column in sheet 2
6. set the paste cell in sheet 1 (first cell with no content in column 1)
7. paste
8. set the copy range in sheet 2 from B2 to the cell with the coordinates (lastColumn|lastRow) ((That's where all the Xes are)
9. set the paste cell in sheet 1. This is the cell after the block of Xes in Sheet 1
10. paste
11. Job is done!

Thanks for your help!

Tom